# Ionic keyboard plugin -phonegap build error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

Trying to build ionic app using phonegap build . I am using ionic keyboard plugin in config file like below

```
<gap:plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" source="npm" version="1.0.7" />
```

It is worked fine till last month. But now I am getting the following error. 
[image]

I refereed npm site https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-plugin-keyboard2. Did not get any idea to fix this issue. Please help .
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by changing plugin name.  In 'npm', it is listed as "ionic-plugin-keyboard", so we are supposed to include it in our config like

```
<gap:plugin  name="ionic-plugin-keyboard"  source="npm" version="1.0.7" />
```